# Text in a <div> on top of a canvas - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and trying to put a `<div>` element on top of a `<canvas>` element so I can overlay some text.

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="div_p5canvas">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center">
                <canvas id="mymap" data-processing-sources="mymap.pde" style="height:auto; width:auto; focus { outline: 0; }" tabindex="1"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The canvas running a processing.js sketch.

Ideally the  would be "transparent" to clicking if that is even possible, allowing for interaction with the canvas below.

The canvas is automatically resized depending on the size of the browser window. Is there  method to obtain a canvas elements size and match a div to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't know how to do it with your html, so I wrote my own:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=640 height=480></canvas>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Hello there</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Be careful with the pointer-events: none; as the browser support is not the best: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

http://codepen.io/jonigiuro/pen/jdtKl

Comment: Thanks, what I realised I neglected to mention was that the canvas is dynamically resized as the window is resized. Is there a method to obtain the size of the canvas and fit a div to it?